# EvaluateJavascript does not work in Webview flutter. Why isn't the JS fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, webview

I am using `evaluateJavascript` with js code
`document.getElementsByTagName ('main') [0] .style.display = 'none'` but it fails `_webController.evaluateJavascript ("document.getElementsByTagName ('main') [0] .style.display = 'none'", );`

I have already tried everything in order to perform my own JS on the webview page, JS is not performed in any way.
What could be the problem ?? Why is it not working?

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
          splash: Image.asset(
            'assets/animation.gif',
          ),
          nextScreen: YellowBird(),
          // nextScreen: MainScreen(),
          splashTransition: SplashTransition.slideTransition,
        ),
      );
    }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  late WebViewController _webController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialUrl: 'http://212.80.206.193/test.project-270.com/',
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  _webController = controller;
                  _webController.clearCache();
                },
               
                onPageStarted: (url) {
                  _webController.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].style.display ='none'",);
                },
                navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                  print(request.url);
                  if (request.url.contains("geo:")) {
                    launch(request.url);
                    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                  } else {
                  return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MainLocation createState() => MainLocation();
}

class MainLocation extends State<StatefulWidget> {
  Location location = new Location();
  late bool _isSeviceEnabled;
  late PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
  late LocationData _locationData;
  bool _isListenLocation = false, _isGetLocation = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async{
              _isSeviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
              if(!_isSeviceEnabled){
                _isSeviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
                if (_isSeviceEnabled) return;
              }

              _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
              if(_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied){
                _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
                if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) return;
              }
              _locationData = await location.getLocation();
              setState(() {
                  _isGetLocation = true;
              });
            }, child: Text('Get Location')),
            _isGetLocation ? Text('Location: ${_locationData.latitude} ${_locationData.longitude}') : Container(),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async{Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));}, child: Text('Proceed')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );  
  }
}
```

Please help me solve this problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong with your code:

1. The `_webController.evaluateJavascript` should be in the **`onPageFinished`**, not on the `onPageStarted`, that callback is invoked when the page starts loading, so if you execute Javascript in that moment you get an error since the page hasn't loaded yet.
2. You are in a statless widget and you are reassigning the controller variable, this is not good. You should have a `StatefulWidget` and call `setState` when assigning the controller to the variable.

So to solve the issue move the callback on onPageFinished and change your widget to a **Stateful Widget**

```dart
WebView(
        initialUrl: 'exampleUrl',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          setState(() {
            _controller = webViewController;
          });
        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) async {
          await _controller?.evaluateJavascript('your js code');
        },
);
```

Comment: Riccardo thank you very much for an adequate explanation. Everything worked out and works!

Comment: didn't helped for me, js script is not loading, maybe it is a bug

Comment: Point 2 of this solution is not accurate. You ONLY invoke `setState()` when you want the Flutter Widget Tree to be redrawn (i.e. to essentially update GUI components of your app). You can assign & update variables without calling `setState()` and your code should work perfectly. So only Point 1 is valid for this solution.

Comment: "JavaScript mode must be enabled/unrestricted when calling evaluateJavascript"

Answer (score 4):

```js
_webViewController.evaluateJavascript('JS code');
```

This code is deprecated, Use this instead:

```js
_webViewController.runJavascriptReturningResult('JS code');
```

Comment: Couldn't find any function namely: runJavascriptReturningResult

Comment: @Pawan update your package to the latest version by running `flutter pub upgrade`